# Dynamic Assignment of Variables from One File in Another File [Python]

Tags: python, dynamic, variable-assignment

I need to dynamically assign variables from one file in another file. This was attempted by doing the following. In `file1.py`:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
```

Then in `file2.py`:

```
 import file1

 Class File2
      def assign2(self, varName, val)
           ...
           (do stuff)
           ...
           setattr(file1, varName, val)
           print(str(getattr(file1, varName))) -> 3, 4

      def assign1(self)
           self.assign2("var1", 3)
           self.assign2("var2", 4)
           print(str(getattr(file1, "var1"))) -> 1
           print(str(getattr(file1, "var2"))) -> 2
```

If I simply call `file1.var1 = 3` anywhere in `file2.py` then the update occurs, but for some reason using dynamic assignment with `setattr` does not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can hardly believe this is a [mre]. If you’re doing the exact same `getattr` call, you must get the same result. Regardless of which method you call from. Either `file1` isn’t the same `file1`, or `varName` is not `"var1"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've reworked my code so that I don't have to do dynamic assignments, but for future reference, `exec()` worked, although its dangerous:

```
def assign2(self, varName, val)
       if isinstance(val, (list, np.ndarray, tuple)):
            br = "[]"
            if isinstance(val, tuple):
                 br = "()"
            s = f"file1.{varName} = " + br[0]
            for i in range(len(val)):
                 s += f"{val[i]},"
            s += br[1]
            exec(s)
       else:
            exec(f"file1.{varName} = {val}")
```